# New 'Change the look' options

Tags: theme, sharepoint-on

I just installed a new Developer tenant and noticed some nice changes:

[image]

These options are not available in my other Enterprise tenant. Does anyone know when they'll be released? A footer would be amazing in our Intranet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be available in First release tenants by February 2019.

By end of March 2019, they will be available in all standard release tenants.

Reference - [Organize your SharePoint sites with megamenu navigation and new “change the look” options](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Organize-your-SharePoint-sites-with-megamenu-navigation-and-new/ba-p/328068)

Comment: this will be a good release, ty :)